# One Day Agenda with tables, php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, html-table

I need to create a one day agenda, with the reservations of our study rooms in it.
This agenda should show all the rooms and show the occupied times, like:

```
        8:00  8:15  8:30  8:45  9:00  9:15  9:30 ...
Room 1 |      [username         ]           [username 2
Room 2 |            [username 3     ]
Room 3 |[username 4 ]           [username 5 ...
...and so on
```

So it should be clear from the table that Room 1 is occupied from 8:15-9:00 and 9:30-..., Room2 occupied from...
But also which times the study rooms are free.

And I'm a bit stuck at the mo.

This is the code I already have, but it's incomplete:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
$roomlist = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
$roomresult = mysql_query($roomlist);
    while($roomnames=mysql_fetch_array($roomresult)) {
    $roomid=$roomnames['roomid'];
    $roomname=$roomnames['roomname'];
?>
<td><?= $roomname;?></td>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE roomid = '$roomid' AND (start LIKE '%" . $agenda . "%') ORDER BY start,roomid,end "; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$username=$row["username"];
$aantal=$row["numberingroup"];
$reservationid=$row["reservationid"];
$start=$row["start"];
$end=$row["end"];
$roomid=$row["roomid"];

$startdate = explode(" ",$start);
$startdate[0] = explode("-",$startdate[0]);
$startdate[1] = explode(":",$startdate[1]);
$StartFormat = mktime($startdate[1][0],$startdate[1][1],$startdate[1][2],$startdate[0][1],$startdate[0][2],$startdate[0][0]);
$StartDate = date("d/m/Y",$StartFormat);
$StartTime = date("H:i",$StartFormat);

$stopdate = explode(" ",$end);
$stopdate[0] = explode("-",$stopdate[0]);
$stopdate[1] = explode(":",$stopdate[1]);
$StopFormat = mktime($stopdate[1][0],$stopdate[1][1],($stopdate[1][2]+1),$stopdate[0][1],$stopdate[0][2],$stopdate[0][0]);
$StopDate = date("d/m/Y",$StopFormat);
$StopTime = date("H:i",$StopFormat);

$cell = (strtotime($StopTime)-strtotime($StartTime))/(60*15); //a quarter per cell

?>

<td><?= $username . " " . $cell;?></td>
<?php } ?>

</tr>

<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
</table>`
```

`$cell` is calculated because I figured I needed to know how many cells a reservation needed (so one per quarter), but I'm stuck now on how to calculate the free slots, and how to implement all that in a table.

UPDATE:
structure of table 'reservations'

```
reservationid,start,end,roomid,username
41,2014-01-06 08:00:00.000000,2014-01-06 08:59:59.000000,28,stefdg
```

Comment: Already made some progress:
Added all the quarters to the table like <td class="quarter">00</td> so that there is a fixed number of cells for the day.
Update `<td><?= $username . " " . $cell;?></td>` to `<td class="quarter" colspan="<?= $cell;?>"><?= $username . " " . $cell;?></td>`

So now all I need to figure out now is the empty timeslots and how to get those in on the right place.

Comment: What is the structure of the tables? Are the start dates and end dates always on the 15 minute boundary?

Comment: start and end dates are always in the 15 minute boundary (so never 9:38 for example)
Added row from the table reservations to the original question.

Comment: Already thought of doing something like `$startcell = date("Gi",$StartFormat);` so that my html knows to start on which cell in the table, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: I would suggest having a sub query that generates a list of all the possible slots, then you join this against the actual bookings (use a LEFT JOIN). Hence empty slots are in the result set but with empty reservation details.

Comment: @Kickstart That sounds like a very good idea, though at the moment I don't really have an idea how to do that. I will definitly look into how I can do that, but if you have any hints or directions, they are absolutely welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As basic example piece of SQL to give you some idea of how to return a range of possible time slots / room combinations and join that against your reservations

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooms
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR), INTERVAL ((units.a + tens.a * 10) * 15) MINUTE) AS TimeSlotStart
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
    (SELECT 0 AS a UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    WHERE units.a + tens.a * 10 <= 40
) TimeSlots
LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations ON rooms.roomid = reservations.roomid AND TimeSlots.TimeSlotStart >= start AND TimeSlots.TimeSlotStart < end
```

Note, not quite sure what your end value applies to (ie, if a reservation finishes at 9:00, I am assuming that has nothing to do with the time slot that starts at 9:00)

EDIT - scraipt based on yours to output the table of details. This is just putting out xxx for any time slot that a room is occupied for.

```
<html>
</html>
<body>
<table>

<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, 'test');

$sql = "SELECT a.timeslot_start, b.roomid, b.roomname, TIME(c.start) AS start
        FROM timeslots a
        CROSS JOIN rooms b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN reservations c
        ON b.roomid = c.roomid
        AND a.timeslot_start >= TIME(c.start) 
        AND a.timeslot_start < TIME(c.end)
        ORDER BY b.roomid, a.timeslot_start";

$roomresult = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($roomnames=mysqli_fetch_assoc($roomresult)) 
{
    $room_bookings[$roomnames['roomid']][] = $roomnames;
}

$first_room = reset($room_bookings);

echo "<table>";
$FirstRoomDetails = reset($room_bookings);

$Header = array(0=>array("<td></td>"), 1=>array("<td></td>"));
foreach($FirstRoomDetails AS $aRoomTimeSlot)
{
    $TimeSlotSplit = explode(':', $aRoomTimeSlot['timeslot_start']);
    if ($TimeSlotSplit[1] == '00')
    {
        $Header[0][] = "<td colspan='4'>".$TimeSlotSplit[0]."</td>";
    }
    $Header[1][] = "<td>".$TimeSlotSplit[1]."</td>";
}
echo "<tr>".implode('', $Header[0])."</tr>\r\n";
echo "<tr>".implode('', $Header[1])."</tr>\r\n";

foreach($room_bookings AS $aRoomsBookings)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $First = true;
    foreach($aRoomsBookings AS $aRoomTimeSlot)
    {
        if ($First)
        {
            $First = false;
            echo "<td>".$aRoomTimeSlot['roomname']."</td>";
        }
        echo "<td>".(($aRoomTimeSlot['start'] == '') ? '' : 'xxxx')."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\r\n";
}
echo "<table>";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will do my best to understand this query and apply it.

The end value is there so the system knows when a room is available again. There it ends at -1 second, so the same room is available again from 9:00:00. These two reservations have nothing to see with other, they have a different reservationid. (Hope this answers your question?)

Comment: That is what I assumed (hence using >= for the start and < for the end on the last join, rather than using BETWEEN)

Comment: Since I'm quite an SQL-noob, would it be easier for me if I created an extra table in my database for the timeslots? Like: `timeslot_id,timeslot_start,timeslot_end|1,08:00:00,08:14:59|1,08:15:00,08:29:59` and so on, and then tried to JOIN these two tables? Are am I making things more dificult for me?

Comment: As a one off it might well be easier and probably more efficient, but less flexible. Generating a range of values is a useful trick to know.

Comment: I get that. I will do my very best to do my research so I can apply your solution.

Comment: Forgive me for being slow, but I'm trying to understand this (because nobody ever learned anything from copy-paste). What I have to do is create a possible timeslot for every 15 minutes, between 8:00 and 18:00 per roomid? Then the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` replaces those slots with the actual reservation, when available? Just asking this so I can make my searches for info more clear.

Comment: Yes. This way you force an entry for every possible time slot, and populate the details if there is a reservation for that time slot. This means that you can sort the results into the appropriate order (by room, and by time slot) and you can then just loop around the results to output them directly to a table without having to try and code to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Babysteps, but I'm getting somewhere I think. I did create a table with the timeslots (even though it is a less flexible way), and now I get empty cells for each slot.
`<?php $roomlist = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
$roomresult = mysql_query($roomlist); while($roomnames=mysql_fetch_array($roomresult)) { $roomid=$roomnames['roomid'];
$roomname=$roomnames['roomname'];
?>
<td><?= $roomname;?></td>
<?php
$TimeSlots = "SELECT * FROM timeslots";
$allslots = mysql_query($TimeSlots);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($allslots)) {
$slot=$data['timeslot_start'];
echo "<td>" . $username . "</td>";
}
</tr>`

Comment: Now I will read and try to find out how to LEFT JOIN the reservations table with it.

Comment: Joins are very important in relational databases. With a normal join (INNER JOIN) you get a row for every combination of matching rows, but if there is no matching row on one table (say table a) for a row on the other (say table b) than no row would be returned despite the existence of a row on table a. With a LEFT OUTER JOIN if there were a row on table a but no matching row on table b, then you would get a row returned but the fields from table b would be NULL.

Comment: By the way, a CROSS JOIN is joining all rows from one table to another getting every possible combination with no matching conditions. Hence my SQL example doing a cross join between the rooms and the available time slots, giving you every possible room / time slot combination.

Comment: But when I try to cross join rooms and timeslots I get a new row for every timeslot, and not a new cell?

Comment: Nothing obvious. However what does the $agenda field contain? Can you put up your table definitions and some sample data (posting on http://www.sqlfiddle.com is probably easier)

Comment: Deleted the comment because I noticed why it didn't work. `$agenda` contains a date via $_POST, to select on which day I want the agenda.

Comment: These are the tables used: http://pastebin.com/3UBddPW7 and my file to print the agenda http://pastebin.com/pVxL4gRa

Comment: I have knocked up a script based on yours to put out the details. Also it puts out the time slot headings based on the results rather than hard coded.

Comment: I bow for you! Thank you very much. This indeed works like a charm. Added `AND c.start LIKE ('%" . $agenda . "%')` to the query, so I can pick the date. But it's frigging perfect.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, and sorry to bother you after all your help, but how can I get the username to display in the fields? Whatever I try just returns empty.

Comment: You need to add it as a field in the SELECT clause. You were using SELECT *, which while a useful tool when knocking some test SQL is a bit risky for production use. Instead of * you can (and should) specify a comma separated list of column names.

Comment: I did that, the clause now says `SELECT a.timeslot_start, b.roomid, b.roomname, TIME(c.start), c.username AS start` but whatever I try I can't get the `username` to show up. I tried to get it as `$roomnames['username']`,`$room_bookings['username']` , ... (probably missing something very obvious here, but I can't seem to find it)

Comment: When I do `print_r($room_bookings);` the usernames show up on the right place, so they come correctly from the database. (`[4] => Array ( [timeslot_start] => 09:00:00 [roomid] => 28 [roomname] => M01 [TIME(c.start)] => 09:00:00 [start] => naommard )`) Where _naommard_ is the username.

Comment: SOLVED: Looking at the output from `print_r()` I found out I needed to name it `$aRoomTimeSlot['start']`. Display correct now.

Comment: Problem is that you have aliased the wrong column to be called start. It should be SELECT a.timeslot_start, b.roomid, b.roomname, TIME(c.start) AS start, c.username

Comment: That makes so much sense I should have figured it out right away... Edited my SELECT clause and `$username = $aRoomTimeSlot['username']; $user = substr($aRoomTimeSlot['username'], 0, 5);` and it works like a charm now. Thank you very much!